# how to stop python script when running in workspace jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I made a pythonscript that opens an excel file and loads it into a df.

Running the script in Jupyterlab gives memory issues. Problem was in the amount of columns in the original excel file. I made an adjusted excel file with less columns and now I can't clear the workspace in Jupyterlab and restart the code. Everytime when I start Jupyterlab it continues running the script that is in the workspace and I am not able to stop. After a while I get the performance warning and Opera shuts down Jupyterlab.

how can I clear the workspace.